# Is there an Powershell/Azure-CLI or even a portal option to copy a formula to creare VMs in Azure?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli, azure-devtest-labs

I have two azure subscriptions and I have a formula in one of them who is inside a **Azure DevTest Labs** I have searched for it on the documentation but I couldn't find anything what I found was scripts to copy VMs, however, that is not what I need because in that way the VM has to be already created and **what I want it's copy the formula I have in subscription 1 to subscription 2**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can programatically create formulas using [ARM templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/).  A sample template for creating a DevTest formula is [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-devtestlab/tree/177a45ce914537b17680b05a3e6f8e5913fe2d53/samples/DevTestLabs/QuickStartTemplates/201-dtl-create-formula).  I don't have a DevTest lab created but most resources in the Azure Portal have an "Automation Script" blade that will show the current ARM structure, you can pull your existing formula from there.

[image]

Comment: thanks it helped me to download a template for my resouce group that there is a script to create the formula